# oh my zsh with git plugin, how to auto completion with filename

Tags: oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

[my terminal picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi18n.jpg)

In that case,I want add 1.txt ,I must type `ga tmp/caches/1.txt`, how can i just type `ga 1.txt` and help me auto complete full file path.
I've installed `zsh-autosuggestions zsh-completions`, but they were helpless.

I want some plugin can help me do that,but i don't know